# How can I tell what kind of whitespace is in a string?

Tags: php, asp-classic, screen-scraping

I am scraping some information from a [10 year old website](http://franklinacademy.org/info_schedule.asp) that was built in ASP using Frontpage(originally) and Dreamweaver(lately).  I am using PHP.

I am getting back strings with whitespace that is not spaces. Using the PHP trim function, some of the white space is removed but not all.

```
original string: string(47) "  School Calendar"
trimmed string: string(34) " School Calendar"
```

How do I figure out what the whitespaces are so I can remove them?

My page showing var_dumps of the original and trimmed strings is [here](http://ejgejg.com/fa_web/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like (if you view source on your page), that you're string has `&nbsp;` "spaces" that aren't being trimmed by PHP's trim function.

The best option is probably to replace these in advance, by calling [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) prior to trim:

`$stringToTrim = str_replace("&nbsp;"," ", $original);`

`$trimmed = trim($stringToTrim);`

(Not using standard code formatting because it wasn't handling the `&nbsp;` correctly)

Comment: this won't work if the code actually has a non-breaking space (rather than the html code for one).

Answer (score 1):

`echo ord($trimmed_string)` will tell you what the character code of the whitespace in that example is.  (It gives the character code of the first character.)

Answer (score 1):

Unicode has a plenty of "different" spaces:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_%28punctuation%29#Table_of_spaces

http://www.brunildo.org/test/space-chars.html

Trim doesn't know about them all. You should use regex to get rid of them all if you need.